# I want to compare the row count of two different Excel files in SSIS get an email alert

Tags: excel, ssis, count, comparison, row

I am looking for a way to compare the row count of two Excel files in SSIS, and if the row count of one of the files is >= the row count of the second, I would like to receive an email informing me of this. Is this something I can do in Visual Studio, and if so, how?

Comment: Yes, this is something you can do in Visual Studio.  Can you [edit] into your question some details about what you've tried to do so far?  Using `Excel.Interop` is fairly straight-forward.  Consider reading [ask], and try to provide a [mcve] where it shows any trouble you ran into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd structure it like this

[image]

I have 4 SSIS variables defined. Two of them will be used in the data flows to capture the amount of rows generated from the sources.

The other two have Expressions applied to them to calculate values.

```
@[User::RowCountFile1] >  @[User::RowCountFile2]
```

That generates a true/false value that I will use in Send Email to determine whether there is any work (email) to be done.

Since I'm lazy, I also used an Expression to generate the body of the email

```
"The value of  File1 is " +  (DT_WSTR,20) @[User::RowCountFile1] + " and File2 is " +  (DT_WSTR,20) @[User::RowCountFile2]
```

Both data flow tasks look like this

[image]

The final configuration is to add an Expression to the Send Email task and change the Disable property to be driven by the our `@[User::IsFile1BiggerThan2]` variable.

Comment: If I wanted to have this same package execute comparing file 1 to multiple files (in the same directory) how would I go about that? Basically after checking File 1 against File 2, checking File 1 against File 3, File 1 against File 4, etc.

Comment: Too many "it depends" to give an authoritative answer but if I had to compare the row count of one file against many, I'd likely have a foreach loop enumerate over all the files. For each file found, count the rows. Then I'd have an Execute SQL Task store the counts into a table. Once all the files have been counted, I'd then look at the results and send emails as appropriate. The other lazy/copy paste approach would be to repeat what we've done to solve File2 and make variables for File3, File4 etc and follow the pattern

Comment: I've followed the above steps -- but when I test out the program after making the row sizes different (file 1 different than file 2) the Boolean is still returning false. Is there any troubleshooting tips you have?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the email sending task and then inspect the values of your RowCount variables. Do they match what you expect to see? I have had instances where Excel only had 50 records but the Excel Source would send me a few hundred records - like there were crumbs from previous rows that hadn't been fully cleaned up. Data was all blanks, but rows were sent none-the-less.

Comment: The values on the RowCount variables seem to be coming up as 0 every time.

Comment: In that case, either the Excel Source is sending zero row; the row count transformation isn't using the expected variable; or you inspected the Variables window during the breakpoint (which will show the design-time values). If thats' the case, you will want to go into the Debug menu and there is a ~ inspect variables menu (mobile atm so name approxmiate) and you'll have to click through a few layers to find the SSIS variable values at run time

Comment: You can use the row viewer in the data flow task to validate that rows are being sent from the Excel Source to rule that one out

Comment: Using the data viewer the rows seem to be passing through, but through, and it is showing the correct number of rows, but it seems like Row Count is not assigning a value to the variable.

Comment: This appears to be resolved. I used C# and ran a script that confirms the variables appear to be holding values.

Answer (score 0):

first solution is : read excel file and load to data table ,then run query for compare two data table ,then send email .
second solution is : when you read file by query select row count in bind in value1 and value2 then compare.